# tlsverify - gitlab pipeline - DIND deprecation warning

Tags: docker, ssl, pipeline

I'm using molecule to test my Ansible roles. I'm using a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to execute a pipeline in which Molecule is invoked to test the role. The pipeline is configured as [Docker in Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker).

```
---
image: docker:latest

services:
  - name: docker:dind
    entrypoint: ["env", "-u", "DOCKER_HOST"]
    command: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

stages:
  - test

<snip>
```

The pipeline actually runs *without* any errors and my roles are perfectly tested, which is good.

The problem: there are deprecation warnings shown in the output of the pipeline:

```sh
2021-12-27T20:54:55.033126585Z time="2021-12-27T20:54:55.032781033Z" level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found"
2021-12-27T20:54:55.035055413Z time="2021-12-27T20:54:55.032907524Z" level=warning msg="Binding to IP address without --tlsverify is insecure and gives root access on this machine to everyone who has access to your network." host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2021-12-27T20:54:55.035076321Z time="2021-12-27T20:54:55.034207001Z" level=warning msg="Binding to an IP address, even on localhost, can also give access to scripts run in a browser. Be safe out there!" host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2021-12-27T20:54:56.034494370Z time="2021-12-27T20:54:56.034363786Z" level=warning msg="Binding to an IP address without --tlsverify is deprecated. Startup is intentionally being slowed down to show this message" host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2021-12-27T20:54:56.034595755Z time="2021-12-27T20:54:56.034566557Z" level=warning msg="Please consider generating tls certificates with client validation to prevent exposing unauthenticated root access to your network" host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2021-12-27T20:54:56.034665726Z time="2021-12-27T20:54:56.034638945Z" level=warning msg="You can override this by explicitly specifying '--tls=false' or '--tlsverify=false'" host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2021-12-27T20:54:56.034732887Z time="2021-12-27T20:54:56.034688345Z" level=warning msg="Support for listening on TCP without authentication or explicit intent to run without authentication will be removed in the next release" host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2021-12-27T20:55:11.036193082Z tim
```

When I read this, it looks quite serious.

The containers are executed at gitlab.com themselves, I use shared runners.
All my roles have been for development purposes, so I don't really care if someone could read them. They are open-source either way. No production data or sensitive information is stored.

**Question**: How do I configure my pipeline so the depreciation warning is either solved or ignored.

I've tried configuring something along the lines of:

```yaml
variables:
  DOCKER_TLSVERIFY: false
```

But the warning persists.

**Bonus**: how should I fix: `could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found`

Comment: Any particular reason that you don't want to use [Docker-in-Docker with TLS enabled](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-in-docker-with-tls-enabled). That should get rid of the warnings.

Comment: when I set the variable `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"`, the pipeline quits soon because: `ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375/. Is the docker daemon running?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I had to set the following variables:

```yaml
variables:
  # DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/ # not used anymore
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
```